# VueJS: External template file (using a variable)

Tags: templates, vue.js

I want to use a component template depending on the client I have (the client ID is set in the env file)... so what I would like is something like this

```
<template :src="'../themes/' + process.env.VUE_APP_CLIENT + '/assets/views/myComponent.vue'"></template>
```

I get nothing like this, not even an error.... could someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: I assume you are looking to dynamically bind which component to render, probably looking for this https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-dynamic-async.html

Comment: @Gowri how can I use that to load different views for the same component?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Gowri pointed into the right direction.
Your idea is to dynamically put components in the container.

This [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/chrisvfritz/o3nycadu/) will show you the general idea of putting the specific name of the component to `v-bind:is` directive. Or [shorthand](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/syntax.html#v-bind-Shorthand)  `:is`.

I assume that you have all your templates defined and imported to the container component file. As a result, just assign them in `components` section and put the appropriate name to `<component>` tag.

List of [locally registered components](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-registration.html#Local-Registration) might look like:

```
components: {
 'client-1': Client1Template,
 'client-2': Client2Template
}
```

```
<component
    :is="getComponentName"
  ></component>
```

Your getComponentName could look like:

```
computed: {
    getComponentName: function () {
      return process.env.VUE_APP_CLIENT;
    }
  }
```

### Update for dynamic import ( without registering the component )

To load the template without the registration of component you could use Webpack import:

```
<template>
    <component :is="component" v-if="component" />
</template>
<script>
export default {
    data() {
        return {
            component: null,
        }
    },
    computed: {
        loader() {
            if (!process.env.VUE_APP_CLIENT) {
                return null
            }
            return () => import(`themes/${process.env.VUE_APP_CLIENT}/assets/views/myComponent.vue`)
        },
    },
    mounted() {
        this.loader()
            .then(() => {
                this.component = () => this.loader()
            })
            .catch(() => {
                // show an error message or maybe load some default template
                this.component = () => import('themes/defaultClient/assets/views/component.vue')
            })
    },
}
</script>
```

Additionally, I'd suggest you take a look at Functional Component.
It has an almost similar approach to what I've proposed but in Vue way:
https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/render-function.html#Functional-Components

### Update after comments

```
<script lang="ts">
  import { Component } from "vue-property-decorator";
  import MyComponent from "@/components/MyComponent.vue";
  @Component({})
  export default class MyComponentClientName extends MyComponent {}
</script>
```

Comment: hm... from my understanding, this would be 2 different coponents? I don't want to repeat the component logic, (js nor css)... just template .. I want to retain the other logic

Comment: @DS_web_developer got it. Didn't notice that. 
I've updated my answer with dynamic Webpack import and link to Functional Components ( I haven't used them so my knowledge is restricted by documentation only )

Comment: Heya, great, thanks, that helped. The only problems is now passing the props that I have in the component to the vue, I have `@Prop() item: any;` among others and vue is giving me error now that item is not defined in the template

Comment: is it actually loading a whole new component or just the template in themes/..../MyComponent.vue?

Comment: OK, I did it, I passed the props in the component like so:  `<component :is="component" v-if="component" :item="item" ... />` but, most importantly, I needed to extend the template component with my original one.... like `<script lang="ts">
import { Component } from "vue-property-decorator";
import MyComponent from "@/components/MyComponent.vue";

@Component({})
export default class MyComponentClientName extends MyComponent {}
</script>`

this way the whole thing works, well I might add....   Please update the answer

Comment: @DS_web_developer I've added this part to answer.  But in the original question, you didn't mention the params and extending.

Comment: I did say I don't want to repeat the logic, just to display different template (meaning I want to access all the same values I have in the main component) ;)